# YAML Syntax error (Ansible 2.2.1.0)

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm self-learning Ansible with YAML. I wrote a small test to test the hostname in my environment.

```
   ---
     - hosts: all
       tasks:
         - name: get server hostname
           command: hostname
```

but when I ran `ansible-playbook playbooks/hostname.yml` it gave me the error below:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/work/ansible/playbooks/hostname.yml': line 5, column 1, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

      - name: get server hostname
        command: hostname 
^ here
```

I've double checked there is no extra new line. Also, when I remove

```
name: get server hostname
```

It works perfectly fine for me. Could anyone point it out what might cause this issue?

Comment: Please confirm the code you posted, especially the number of spaces in front (if there are any). Also: is this the whole playbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing YAML is sensitive to indentation, so what you posted can be both: correct and incorrect depending on the number of spaces in front. Unless you were very precise it is hard to answer.

Most likely cause for an error in column 1 is a character other than space, however if there was a tab, the error message would indicate that directly.

Use the following code to avoid problems. Copy it to a new file and re-run.

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: get server hostname
      command: hostname
```

<sup>Besides, your task is **not** the correct way to acquire hostname in Ansible, although it might work.</sup>

Comment: I move the file to sublime text. It shows there is an extra line after command, which is hard to notice in Linux shell. what would be the best practice to code YAML in shell?